# r DataTables (DT) border width / colour

Tags: css, r, datatables, dt

Given the table

```
library(DT)

datatable(
  iris,
  style = "default",
  filter = "top",
  class = "hover stripe compact"
)
```

I can adjust the footer border using the following css

```
table.dataTable.no-footer {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

However I can't seem to understand how I can change the border under the column names, nor the border just over the first row of the body. How could this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following css did the trick:

```
table.dataTable thead th, table.dataTable thead td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@aleksip:  Using the rules you provided, the style will not be applied to the td cells, because they are under a tbody, not a thead.  I think you intended the following.

```
table.dataTable.no-footer thead th,
table.dataTable.no-footer tbody td
{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```